# How to identify if AWS EFS is the root volume for Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, aws

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 instance and df- h command returns below output.

```
Filesystem                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                           3.1G  804K  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                   97G   28G   70G  29% /
tmpfs                                            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                                       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop1                                       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
fs-44a34f7c.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /mnt/efs/fs1
/dev/loop2                                       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
tmpfs                                           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Is AWS EFS the root volume in my instance or not?

Comment: /dev/nvme0n1p1 is your root volume.

Comment: How can i change it to the EFS?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.